# How to draw a border around an image

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I googled and don't found a way to create a border as is demonstrated in the images below:

**image whithout border:**

[image]

**image with border**

[image]

How to create a border around the image using C# ? Can anyone give me an example, tip, etc. so that I can create this edge?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you planning to create it from code behind? is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: I'm using windforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing a border on an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858002/drawing-a-border-on-an-image)

Comment: Are you using `Picturebox`?

Comment: Yes I'm using picturebox. I'll see the post Drawing a border on an image, maybe help me.

Comment: That border looks pretty darn specific to that image.  Just use your border image and replace the other one whenever you want to show it.  Swap it out, in other words.

Comment: The post is not duplicated because in fact what the other topic answers not actually creates an edge in the image, but a shading using FillRectangles method. The image itself I posted shows the difference.

Comment: Yes it is also what's making me understand, from what I see I will have to create a second image as a border with the area of the transparent medium and a main color, I.e. white, and according to the user's choice he selects a color for the category of player and the border color changes.
What I'm creating is a poker application replayer hands, where the user of the program will review the hand played and categorize opponent as donkey, TAG, LAG, maniac any two cards etc.